# Where is the mount point and format of the iOS memory when it is plugged in a mac?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, memory, mount

I would like to do manual changes to my iOS iPhone, and I would like to know if it is possible to plug the iOS into a mac, find the mount point and `/dev/disk<number>` and then cd to it and do changes. What is the format of the iOS memory and mount point?

Is it possible to mount the phone if it is not mounted yet? How does iTunes make changes to the phone?

Comment: At this time, I am not at my computer and I forgot my iphone home, so later this day, I am more "available"

Comment: It does not mount - it sets up a connection between the two computers and iTunes has the protocol to interface with the iPhone

Comment: And can I use the protocol to mount the iOS and do manual edits? Or if not mount, just edit it.

Comment: Basically no - what chnage do you want to make?

Comment: Changes that iFile can do (I dont want jailbreak though). Edit .plists, delete apps or manually install them.

Comment: That needs a jailbreak if anything does this

Comment: Ok. Please do an answer on that. I was also thinking about adding some modification to iTunes to help me with editing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the iPhone does not present itself to any computer as a block device, so you won't be able to mount it and access the file system. This is among other things a security feature. Depending on what you are trying to change, you might be able to use iTunes for manually uploading music, playlists and I think possibly videos as well. Additionally you can use iTunes to upload files to any apps that allow it.

If you jailbreak your phone, you get full file system access at which point you can install an ssh daemon and ssh into your phone.

Comment: Can I modify or make a program based on iTunes in some way to write to the filesystem? Jailbreaking sounds like a better option anyway though

Comment: There are no provided hooks or APIs; so there is no _sanctioned_ way to do that to my knowledge, so you'd probably have to go the jailbreak route.
Keep in mind with jailbreaking, it introduces **security concerns and vulnerabilities** because jailbreak inherently bypasses/disables a lot of security mechanisms Apple has built in.